# Replace last word occurrence in file

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

The scenario is I want to comment out the last occurrence of a word in shell script using `sed`.

Assume I have `temp.sh` with the following content:

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

I want to replace the last instance of `Abc` (occurring at the start of a line) with `#Abc`
So finally, the result would be like this:

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

Comment: Your example is missing many of the test cases that scripts often fail on for such problems, e.g. `Abc` contains regexp metachars or is a substring of some other string that appears later in the file, or exists as a word only later in a line, etc. so you're likely to get an answer that'll work for the example you provided but fail later on your real data. The currently accepted answer, for example, would fail if the last line of input was `Abcfoobar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the file, comment out the first, and reverse the file back again:

```
$ tac temp.sh | sed '0,/^Abc/{s/^Abc/#&/}' | tac
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

That means "start at line 0, and continue until the first line matching `/^Abc/` and in those lines only, replace `Abc` with `#` and whatever was matched (`#`) which, in this case, was `Abc`. With thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453461/1081936).

Note that this requires `tac`, a GNU tool, and the GNU implementation of `sed`.

To make the change in the original file, use:

```
tac temp.sh | sed '0,/^Abc/{s/^Abc/#&/}' | tac > temp1.sh &&
  mv temp1.sh temp.sh
```

Or, in Perl:

```
$ tac temp.sh | perl -pe 'next if $k; $k++ if s/^Abc/#$&/ ' | tac
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

To make the change in the original file, use:

```
tac temp.sh | perl -pe 'next if $k; $k++ if s/^Abc/#$&/ ' | tac> temp1.sh &&
  mv temp1.sh temp.sh
```

Or use [Stephane's pure `perl` approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757742/22222) or [Kusalananda's pure `sed` one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757743/22222), both of which use `-i` to edit the original file.

Comment: `s/^Abc/#&/` for the lazy (`s/^Abc/#$&/` in Perl).

Comment: @Kusalananda, really lazy people would use `s//#&/` :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda `s/^/#/` for the really lazy since we already check for `/^Abc/` :)

Comment: I'm not only lazy, but too tired to read properly it seems :-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas eh, only `tac` is a GNU tool, the `perl` approach is portable and the OP is on Linux. But fair enough, note added, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This gives correct output on screen. But it doesn't do in place replacement. My original file remains same, it doesn't have # appended.

Comment: @Curiouscat if you want to edit the file in place (which is something you should have mentioned in the question, by the way), just redirect to a temp file and rename it to the original name.

Comment: Ah! Okay, I was directly redirecting output to original file that caused blank file I guess. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: ... or redirect to `sponge` from moreutils.  Also, some systems without `tac` has `tail -r` which does the same thing.

Comment: The 0 address and missing `;` before `}` are extensions of GNU sed as well.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks @StéphaneChazelas.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
$ sed -e 'H; $!d' -e 'g; s/\n\(.*\n\)\(Abc\)/\1#\2/' file
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

This reads the whole file into the hold space of `sed`, modifies it and outputs the modified text.

The first two `sed` expressions, `H` and `$!d`, append each line to the hold space and then skips to the next cycle (unless we're at the last line of input).

The `g` command is executed for the last line and fetches the contents of the hold space.  The substitution then removes the initial newline that will be there (from appending the first line to the empty hold space) and also inserts a `#` character before the last occurrence of the string `Abc` that is preceded by a newline character.

We are guaranteed to get the *last* `Abc` after a newline because `.*` is greedy and will therefore match as much as possible.

You can use `-i` to edit the file in place (with GNU `sed`, with BSD `sed` you would need `-i '.bak'`):

```
sed -i'.bak' -e 'H; $!d' -e 'g; s/\n\(.*\n\)\(Abc\)/\1#\2/' file
```

---

With the `ed` editor:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' '1;?^Abc?;s//#&/' ,p Q | ed -s file
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

This is essentially performing the edit with a single `ed` editing command, `1;?^Abc?;s//#&/`.  This command first moves the cursor to the first line of the file (`1`; this is necessary in case the `Abc` string is located on the last line), then searches backwards for the last match of the regular expression `^Abc` in the file (`?^Abc?`).  Once found, it inserts a `#` character at the start of the located line (`s//#&/`; this reuses the most recently matched regular expression and uses `&` to insert the matched part of the line after `#`).

The trailing `,p` and `Q` command prints the whole buffer to standard output and then quits unconditionally.

Comment: The `-E` option for `sed` is pretty portable (I know it works with BSD sed, GNU sed, and busybox sed, for instance) and allows for a much simpler syntax here: `sed -Ee 'H; $!d' -e 'g; s/\n(.*\n)(Abc)/\1#\2/' temp.sh`. Is there even a `sed` implementation that understands `\n` but not `-E`?

Comment: @terdon There are no issues with `\n` in this case, and I did not mention `-E` because it's technically not yet standard. If you want to go and look for a `sed` that does not support `-E`, then see the Plan9 `sed` (part of `plan9port` on many systems), but it's true that most implementations support it (which is, I assume, why it's soon in POSIX).  I tend to use extended expressions if I need to, and here I don't strictly need to. I'm on the fence about whether I need to mention the `-E` variant...

Comment: When I ran your first script on a file that only had 1 `Abc` in it and that was the first line of the file, the output I got was a blank line followed by the file contents unchanged.

Comment: @EdMorton That probably means my code does not handle that eventuality. I will update the answer when I find time to do so.

Answer (score 2):

###### With `awk` (no pipe(s)):

```
awk -v str=Abc '
    NR==FNR{if ($0 == str) nr_str=NR; next}
     {print (FNR == nr_str) ? "#"$0 : $0}
' file file
```

###### Output

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

Comment: Nice. You might wan to change to `v str='^Abc'` and then `if ($1 ~ str) nr_str=NR;next` because I don't know that we can assume the pattern will always be a word.

Comment: UP to OP if he want to adapt. The logic is the most important part.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to process the file as a whole:

```
perl -pi -0777 -pe 's/.*\K^Abc/#$&/ms' temp.sh
```

Or without regexp and assuming the last occurrence of `Abc` at the start of the line is not on the first line:

```
perl -pi -0777 -e '
  if (($i = rindex($_, "\nAbc")) >= 0) {
    substr($_, $i+1, 0) = "#";
  }' temp.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

Reversing the file, then `awk`'s `sub()` function is used. After that reversing the file again gives expected output.

```
$ tac file |
awk '/^Abc/ && (!found){sub(/^Abc/, "#Abc"); found++}1' |
tac
```

Output

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

---

Without pipe:

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN{rec_rep=""; rec_last=""}
       {if (/^Abc/){ 
                   if (rec_rep) print rec_rep;
                                rec_rep = $0;
                                sub(/^Abc/, "#Abc"); 
                                rec_last = $0; 
                                }
          
                   else {       rec_rep = ((rec_rep) ? rec_rep ORS : "") $0;
                                rec_last = ((rec_last) ? rec_last ORS : "") $0 }
  }
  END{print rec_last}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my $i=0; lines.reverse.map( *.subst: /^Abc <?{$i++ == 0}> /, {"#$/"} ).reverse.join("\n").put;'  file > tmp
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -e 'my $i=0; lines.reverse.map( *.subst: /^(Abc) <?{$i++ == 0}> /, {"\#$0"} ).reverse.join("\n").put;'  file > tmp
```

The answer above is coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku doesn't do "in-place" editing, so you'll have to save to a `tmp` file then over-write the original.

I thought it would be fun to eliminate `tac` or `tail -r` from the answer, so the file is read linewise with `lines`, then `reverse`d twice. Reading linewise can help if the file is very large (as opposed to `slurp`ing the file in all at once). Because `lines` autochomps, newlines have to be added back at the end.

Lines are kept separate, so an `$i` iterator variable has to keep track of substitutions. The crux of the answer can be found in the `.subst`itution method call, which is `map`ped over each line:

`.map( *.subst: /^Abc <?{$i++ == 0}> /, {"#$/"} )`

Right in the middle of the `/ .../` regex matcher you'll see a [Regex Boolean Condition Check](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_Boolean_condition_check) that limits regex substitution to one line. If `$i++` is `0` the substitution will be performed, while on subsequent matches to `^Abc` the `$i` iterator will `==` numerically equal `1` or greater, thus causing those subsequent matches to be skipped. FYI, `$/` represents the match variable in Raku (alternatively `$<>` can be used).

Sample Input:

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

Sample Output:

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Yet, another `awk` solution:

```c
awk '{
        lines[NR] = $0
        /^Abc/ && (n = NR)
}

END {
        lines[n] = "#" lines[n]
        for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
                print lines[i]
        }
}' temp.sh
```

... outputs:

```
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

Comment: Use `$0 == "Abc" && (n = NR)` instead of `/^Abc/ && (n = NR)` for exact whole line match.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk this will match the first space-separated string on a line without false matches even if that string contains regexp metachars or that string can appear as a substring of other strings:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if ($1 == "Abc") n=NR; next} n==FNR{printf "#"} 1' file file
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```

or if you have `tac` on your system:

```
$ tac file | awk '!f && ($1 == "Abc"){printf "#"; f=1} 1' | tac
Abc 123 Abc
Sdf 2
Abc
#Abc
Utyr
Qww
```